# React-Native simulate device is disconnected

Tags: react-native

Turning genymotion (or device) wifi causes app be unable to connect to app bundle and goes to show the red error in `react-native`. So how can I simulate app behavior when is disconnected from the internet (and also developing to have a good react (I mean it's not just about testing, also developing))?

Answer (score 2):

There are only 4 states possible:

1. connected with good connection (have access to remote servers)
2. connected with poor connection (loss percentage is high)
3. connected with `zero` connection (have not access to remote servers - 100% loss)
4. not connected

Simulations way depends on which situation you need and where your app is running (device:iOS, Android?, simulator: mac, windows?)

On iOS you have `Developer` menu in the preferences and `Network Link Conditioner` in.
On Mac you can install `Network link conditioner` by [this](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/)

I`m sure android has some tool for it.
Can`t say something about windows, sorry